# How to list all pytest fixtures

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

How can I list all pytest [fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html) in a codebase? Ideally with documentation on each

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can list all pytest fixtures in a repository with the following command

```
pytest --fixtures
```

Comment: Additionally, if you wish to display a list of fixtures for each test, try the `--fixtures-per-test` flag.